# Creating a div and adding it to the page via Greasemonkey and jQuery

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm new to working with Greasemonkey and jQuery and I need to add a settings panel to the current page, when an image is clicked.

Can someone give me an example of how to create a div via jQuery, then add it to the current page, absolutely positioned over the other elements?

Here's some of the test code I'm working with, somewhat blindly to the methods involved.

```
var settingsDiv = '<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;width:500px;padding:0;" id="kwdHelpInfo">This is the div that I want to add to the page</div>';

//the #kwdHelp element is an image file already in the document. When its clicked, I want to show the settingsDiv...

jQuery('#kwdHelp').live('click',function(){
    //alert('clicked show help');
    //var newcell = jQuery(settingsDiv);
    //jQuery(newcell).show();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but not quite there. use jQuery's `append()` method to add your new element to the bottom of a containing element...

```
$('#kwdHelp').click(function() {
    $('#outerElement').append(settingsDiv); // this very well could be $('body') or any element you choose
});
```

... adjust your styling as it suites where the element is then positioned.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider something like:

```
// Create, Append, and Save jQuery object for later reference
// Using appendTo is similar to append in functionality, but it returns the object appended
// Create once; toggle later
var jQ_helpInfo = jQuery("<div id='kwdHelpInfo'> ... </div>").appendTo("body");

// ...potentially add styles here...

// Add the click live event to "show"
jQuery("#kwdHelp").live("click", function() { jQ_helpInfo.show(); });

// Later you can have another event "hide"
jQuery(/* some other element or selector */).live("click", function() { jQ_helpInfo.hide(); });
```

Normally, I would recommend styles in a stylesheet or at least `<style>` tag... However in Greasemonkey, it would actually over-complicate things to embed styles this way. You can still organize your styles with an object...

```
// Define styles
var helpInfo_CSS = {
      "position": "absolute",
      "bottom": 0,
      "width": "500px",
      "padding": 0
    };

// Now apply the styles
jQ_helpInfo.css(helpInfo_CSS);
```

This is of course not a rule, but I added this additional suggestion because you mentioned being new to jQuery and Greasemonkey. It is always nice to start off with some good organizational habits.